# How to pass multiple string literals to function using an array (Without vectors)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, constants

Currently I have this class:

```
class Menu
{
    void setVars(const char*,const char*, const char*);
    const char *item1;
    const char *item2;
    const char *item3;
    Menu(const char *setItem1, const char *setItem2, const char *setItem3)
    {
        setVars(setItem1, setItem2, setItem3);
    }
}

void Menu::setVars(const char *setItem1, const char *setItem2, const char *setItem3)
{
    item1 = setItem1;
    item2 = setItem2;
    item3 = setItem3;
}
```

As you can see, currently this is messy, inefficient, and not scalable (Let's say I wanted 20 items; this would not work well). **How would I rewrite this utilizing arrays?**

Note: I am writing code for a very low-end device so vectors are not an option.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pass `const std::vector<const char*>&`?

Comment: I edited in an important piece of information: vectors will not work in my situation.

Comment: If I passed `const std::array<const char*>&` what would the object constructor look like?

Comment: Are you asking how to construct an array of char*, or is there some problem with not just doing char *arrayOfArraysOfChars[10];?

Comment: The internet is full of documentation for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to look for something like this:

```
class Menu
{
    int nb_items; 
    char **item;
 public: 
    Menu(size_t nb_items) : nb_items(nb_items) {
        item = new char*[nb_items];
    }
    ~Menu() {
        delete [] item; 
    }
    void setVars(size_t n, char*s) {
        item[n]=s;   // asuming it's a unique adress of the string that remains valid
        }

};
```

You could as well add the following operator, to be able to access/replace a menu item directly:

```
char*& operator[] (size_t n) {
    return item[n];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [variadic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

I also like this template based variant:

```
#include <iostream>
class Menu { 
public: 
    template<int N> 
    Menu(const char * (& args)[N])  { 
        for(int i = 0;i<N;i++) 
            std::cerr << args[i] << std::endl; 
    } 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
    static const char * a[] = {"A","B","C","D"}; 
    Menu m(a); 
}
```